Get size in bytes of array items (JSON) efficently using Jackson
Let's say I have a JSON array like:
[
  {...},
  {...},
  {...}
]

What I'd like to do is to find the size in bytes of each item, so for example if the first item was {} that'd be 2.
A way of doing this would be to:

Deserialize it into a List<Object>.
Serialize each item into a String or byte[].
Get the length of each serialized item.

But I'm looking for something more efficient, where I can skip the serialization step.
Deserializing each item into a JSON string would solve this, but I couldn't find a way of making that work, since it isn't officially supported.
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Your question may be more suitable for CodeReview on the StackExchange

Why are you interested in how many bytes each item has? And how do you want it measured - are you more interested in how it appears in the JSON document, or how it would be serialized? In other words, is { } 3 bytes or is it 2, because you don't count whitespace? Any what would you count if the item was a number?

Getting the size of the actual document would be ideal. But it shouldn't matter since it's already minified anyway. @k314159
Also regarding why I'm interested, I just am. Getting the byte size of each item is the end-goal. (It'll be sent through a metric system blah blah, it's irrelevant).

There's literally no code to review. @ControlAltDel

You probably cannot skip the Serialization step because it depends on details of serialization how much bytes the serialized version of your objects need - the String encoding (UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.), whether it is pretty-printed etc.
A possible method that needs less memory would be if you implement your own subclass of java.io.Writer or java.io.OutputStream that doesn't actually write anything, but just counts the "written" or "output" bytes, then use that with Jackson to "serialize" your objects. In the end read out the byte count and you're done.

That's a decent option. Theoretically, I feel like I should be able to avoid the serialization step, because the information I want is already available during the deserialization. This seemed promising but sadly it depends on the parser being used.

Use an ÒutputStreamWriter with a null output stream

@g00se how does that count the bytes that were sent into the OutputStream ?

@cyberbrain you'd have to do that yourself by writing a buffer to the Writer

On second thoughts, something like ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();objectMapper.writeValue(out, rootElement);int size = out.toByteArray().length; might be easier

@g00se No need to get a byte array, just do int size = out.size(). Or, to avoid writing at all, just create a very simple subclass of OutputStream that simply counts how many times write(int) has been called.

Hehe for some reason I never knew about that method

@k314159 that's exactly what my answer suggests

An alternative to @cyberbrain's solution, if you're using Jackson, is to use ObjectMapper.readTree and iterate the returned JsonNode, serializing each array element by calling toString() and checking its length:
var om = new ObjectMapper();
var jn = om.readTree("[{\"item1\": 0.000123}, {\"item2\": \"abc\"}]");
if (jn.isArray()) {
    for (JsonNode j : jn) {
        System.out.printf("Item '%s' has size %d%n", j, j.toString().length());
    }
}

This still does serialization but avoids having to write an OutputStream.
